# Finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $y=\int \limits_{\sin x}^{\cos x}(\cos(\pi t^2)) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

If we have: $y=\int \limits_{\sin x}^{\cos x}(\cos(\pi t^2)) dt$

And i want to find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, so my question is: can i find it without calculating the integral?

Because $y'=(\cos(\pi t^2))$.

If so how can i put the the boundaries: $\sin x,\cos x$?

thanks.

Comment: You're wrong about $y'$, in fact $y'=\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$, it's just a different notation. Do you know about the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: i can see what you mean. still, do i have to compute the integral or can i bypass it someway?

Comment: You don't have to compute it, in fact $t\mapsto \cos(\pi t^2)$ doesn't even have an elementary antiderivative, so you'd fail. I repeat, do you know about the FTOC?

Comment: yes i do. $
    F(x) = \int_a^x\!f(t)\, dt$

Comment: take a look here [Differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Comment: @alexjo That's a massive overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Git Gud suggested, using FTOC gives:
$$\frac{d}{dx}y = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sin{x}}^{\cos{x}}\cos{\pi t^2}\ dt = \frac{d}{dx}[F(\cos{x})-F(\sin{x})]$$
where $F'(t) = \cos(\pi t^2)$. Now, use the chain rule.

Edit: Continuing, and using $F'(t) = \cos(\pi t^2)$ we get:
\begin{align}
\notag \frac{d}{dx}[F(\cos{x})-F(\sin{x})] &= \frac{d}{du}F(u)\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{d}{dw}F(w)\frac{dw}{dx}\\
\notag &= F'(u)\cdot(-\sin{x}) - F'(w)\cdot\cos{x}\\
\notag &= -\cos(\pi u^2)\sin{x}-\cos(\pi w^2)\cos{x}\\
\notag &= -\cos(\pi\cos^2{x})\sin{x}-\cos(\pi\sin^2{x})\cos{x}
\end{align}
For the above, the only tricky thing to note is that $u(x) = \cos{x}$, and $w(x) = \sin{x}$. Or maybe it would help to say:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[F(u(x))-F(w(x))] = F'(u(x))u'(x)-F'(w(x))w'(x).$$

Comment: There's a $t$ in the last equality instead of an $x$

Comment: Ah right, good catch, thanks

Comment: @chs21259 - can you show me how to use the chain rule in here? im a bit confused. thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll continue the example above

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $f(t)=\cos(\pi t^2)$ and $$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t) dt$$
so we have
$$F'(x)=f(x)$$
Notice that
$$y=F(\cos x)-F(\sin x)$$
so use the chain rule to find $y'$.

Comment: how can i use the chain rule here?

Comment: What's the derivative of $F(cos x)$? How we derivate $f\circ g$?

Comment: I am late here but this is from mine :+)